# google maps API - "toGeoJson" returns object with geometry null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson, google-maps-drawing

I'am using the google maps Drawing Layer (Library) to draw shapes on my map.

Once finished drawing all the shapes I call "toGeoJson" function from the google maps api.

The object i receive look like this:

[object received when calling "toGeoJSON"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY5UE.png)

I can't figure out what I'am doing wrong.

I am just trying to create a GeoJson out of the shapes drawn on the map.

I am not pasting any code because the drawing part is all done by the drawing library and the "toGeoJson" function is done by the google maps API.

Comment: Related question: [Export geoJSON data from Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072069/export-geojson-data-from-google-maps)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `toGeoJSON` method on the [drawing manager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManager), that only exists on the [Data class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)

Drawing objects on the map with the drawing manager doesn't add them to the DataLayer.

You can add the objects from the drawing manager to the Data Layer, then call `toGeoJson` on that.

To prevent adding duplicate objects to the map, use a separate Data object, rather than the one on the map.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ezfe2wLg/57/)

(some code from the related question: [Export geoJSON data from Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072069/export-geojson-data-from-google-maps))

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  var dataLayer = new google.maps.Data();
  // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072069/export-geojson-data-from-google-maps
  // from http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5F88D/
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER:


        dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point(event.overlay.getPosition())
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE:
        var b = event.overlay.getBounds(),
          p = [b.getSouthWest(), {
              lat: b.getSouthWest().lat(),
              lng: b.getNorthEast().lng()
            },
            b.getNorthEast(), {
              lng: b.getSouthWest().lng(),
              lat: b.getNorthEast().lat()
            }
          ]
        dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([p])
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON:
        dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([event.overlay.getPath().getArray()])
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE:
        dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.LineString(event.overlay.getPath().getArray())
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE:
        dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          properties: {
            radius: event.overlay.getRadius()
          },
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point(event.overlay.getCenter())
        }));
        break;
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('save'), 'click', function() {
    dataLayer.toGeoJson(function(obj) {
      document.getElementById('geojson').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
    });
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="save" value="save" type="button" />
<div id="geojson"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```